# Retry with 30 minutes delay

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-retry, retrytemplate

I need to call a external rest service, if it fails on first attempt then I have to call again after 30 minutes. Max 3 time I can call like this.
I know spring has RetryTemplate for the retry. But I feel, for my cases its not fit. I have to call like this for more than 1000 records.

Any idea How can I achieve this in Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TaskScheduler`.

```
scheduler.schedule(() -> { ... }, 
    new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (30 * 60_000));
```

Keep track of how many times and if not exhausted, re-schedule.